# How to Decompile NW.js exe

Tags: node-webkit

I would like to decompile a JavaScript app compiled with NW.js, trasformed to .exe
I have nw.exe, nw.pak, index.html, package.json, resource dir, and some other folders.
Launching nw.exe it runs perfectly, but I would like to modify it, and I need the source code.

Does exist a way to get JavaScript sources back from the exe?

Answer (score 0):

there are many *many* ways to package an NW.js app. They're all documented on the website. but here are some easy things you can try.

1. **Unlikely, but possible:** Rename the .exe to .zip and open it. there may be project files. Most apps aren't packaged this way because it makes every launch of the app slow, since it has to unzip the contents on every opening and copy them to a temp folder. Plus the zip would contain your `package.json` which you already have, so this likely is not related to your case.
2. the `package.json` should be the entry point, I assume the `index.html` is what it will point to for the `"main"` value inside that file. The `index.html` will then pull in all the other files. Some of these may be online on a server, meaning you can't edit them locally. Some may be in a local folder, probably the "resources" folder, since that is not something that ships with NW.js by default.
3. It is possible that a light version of the app is shipped and the core contents are downloaded/replaced as it is updated. If I were doing this, I would store it in the appData folder. You can find this location by doing `console.log(nw.App.dataPath)`. It is a user account specific folder that will be in a folder that users the App's name as defined in the `package.json`. Though this is unlikely, it is possible.
4. It is possible to "protect" the original source code by using V8 snapshots. If this was used, you will not be able to recover the original source code. To date, there are no recorded cases of someone reverse engineering a V8 snapshot. Though it is possible, it would require an extremely high technical skill level and knowledge across several disciplines.
5. The source code you find may also be "uglified". Meaning, though it would all be there, it would be completely obscured, making it pretty useless to read. Instead of

```js
function getUserData (url) {
  axios.get(url)
  .then(function (response) {
    return response.data;
  })
}
```

it would be something like

```js
function a(b){c.d(b).then(e=>e.f)}
```

not super obvious what is going on when uglified.